# Client-side form validation in play framework

Tags: html, validation, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I want to do this type of validation in my form
[image]

The field should be red with the message when user submits an empty form.
My **create.scala.html**

```
@(signupForm: Form[models.Member])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main(Html("Create User")) {

    @form(action = routes.UserController.submit(), 'id -> "userCreationForm", 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form") {
        <fieldset>
           <legend><h1> Account Information</h1></legend>

<div class="form-group">
            @inputText(signupForm("firstName"),
            '_label -> "First name:",
            'class -> "form-control",
            '_help -> "Please enter your first name.")
            </div>

<div class="form-group">
            @inputText(signupForm("lastName"),
            '_label -> "Last name:",
            'class -> "form-control",
            '_help -> "Please enter your last name.")
            </div>

<div class="form-group">
            @inputText(signupForm("email"),
                        '_label -> "Email Address:",
                        'class -> "form-control",
                        '_help -> "Enter a valid email address.",
                        '_error -> signupForm.globalError)
                        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            @inputPassword(signupForm("password"),
                            '_label -> "Password:",
                            'class -> "form-control",
                            '_help -> "A password must be at least 6 characters.")
                            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
            <a href="@routes.ApplicationController.index" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    }

}
```

and added  `<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` to my **main.scala.html**

but its not giving the desired output means not showing the message and fields with red when user submits an empty form
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Play has no built-in solution for front-end form validation, you need to use some lib i.e. [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

The validation you showed us from sample forms app is a **backend** one - it has constraints set in the model(s) and/or form(s) like in [User.java](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/samples/java/forms/app/models/User.java#L13) model.

More about constraints in the [Forms documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms)

Comment: but in their forms (in samples folder) they used this property,above image is of form.scala.html in forms application and they din't include any other file in their main.scala.html

Comment: here  `\play-2.2.1\samples\java\forms`

Comment: added that constraints to my model but my form still giving same output